# read the text file column wise from specify line using console application c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file

```
maker no.  = 178    05/03/18 11:55:23

ROD       WTg    SIZEmmL OVALmm  PDmm
1      0.740    23.94   0.28    357
2      0.751    23.98   0.29    368
3      0.733    23.95   0.39    351
4      0.747    23.99   0.32    363
5      0.734    23.96   0.23    356

6      0.742    23.89   0.64    365
7      0.745    23.98   0.39    366
8      0.739    23.93   0.29    361
9      0.745    23.98   0.39    366
10      0.739    23.93   0.29    361

n =  10

WTg     SIZEmmL OVALmm  PDmm

MEAN    0.7411  23.946   0.364  361.1
SD      0.0060   0.037   0.115    5.2
MIN     0.733   23.88    0.23   351
MAX     0.751   23.99    0.64   368

11:09:36
********************************************************************************
```

What I wanted to do is read this text file column wise and store every column into separate Array. then write those into another file. That output file should be like

```
<DATA SampleID="1" WTg="0.740" SIZEmmL ="23.94" OVALmm  ="0.28" />
<DATA SampleID="2" WTg="0.751" SIZEmmL ="23.98" OVALmm  ="0.29" />
<DATA SampleID="3" WTg="0.733" SIZEmmL ="23.95" OVALmm  "0.39" />
```

I want to print another columns also as I shown above.
what I have done so far is

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\\ProcessFolderFile.txt")))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open("D:\\ResultFile.txt", FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] columns = line.Split(' ');

                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "<DATA>");
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, columns[1]);
                        WriteAndPrint(writer, "</DATA>");

                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void WriteAndPrint(StreamWriter writer, string line)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

But it won't print as I expect

Comment: Please provide us your attempts to resolve this and what issues you faced..

Comment: The first value in your output is 0.889, it does not appear in your input.

Comment: "every column into separate Array" is a bad design. Consider writing a class with properties.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you please check now sir

Comment: Can you please give me any hint to solve this problem?

Comment: The transformation looks more like simply rowwise. I.e. it's mostly about adding some tags around the figures and maybe omitting some rows. Can you explain what you mean with "columnwise" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to filter the data.

You seem to be in luck that the relevant lines all start with a number, and none of the other lines do.

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] columns = line.Split(' ');

    if(columns.Length != 5) continue;
    if (! int.TryParse(cxolums[0]))  continue;

    // now you know you have 5 columns, at positions 0..4

}
```

Comment: it won't work. Actually it didn't gives error.and also it not to print output

Comment: No, it is not a complete program. It's just to get you started.